# Force a single instance of a resource in a terraform module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I'm creating a terraform module to create an API gateway instance. I expect to instantiate the module multiple times, but API gateway requires a single account wide resource:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_account" "api_gateway_account" {
  cloudwatch_role_arn = aws_iam_role.api_gateway_cloudwatch_global.arn
}
```

Is it possible to create this resource and it's dependencies inside the module and force any new instances to refer to the same resource? The behavior I'm looking for is similar to the singleton pattern in OOP.

Comment: You would have to manage it outside of the module and provide its exported attributes as inputs to the module declarations as necessary. Alternativaly, there are some hacky solutions like a variable declaration where one module declaration manages the resource and the others retrieve it with data.

Comment: Create and pass in is the current pattern I'm using, but this is getting used across a couple teams and accounts. The closer it can be to drop in and use the better.